# Hide scrolling inside scrollable tag

Tags: html, css

I need to scroll parts of a div and ignore scrolling on other parts.

In my example I need to scroll blue and green but want red to stay on its place.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DaWa/dvq8nu4e/)

```html
<div style="width: 100px; 
    height:200px; 
    border: solid black 1px; 
    overflow-x: auto">
  <div style="width: 120px; height: 50px;background-color:blue">
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 30px;background-color:red">
  </div>
  <div style="width: 120px; height: 50px;background-color:green">
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed`:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100px; 
  height:200px; 
  border: solid black 1px; 
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#blue {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:blue;
}

#red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:red;
  position: fixed;
}

#green {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. In my real code I already use a position: block attribute on the tag so I can not use fixed. Is there an other way to fix the tag?

Comment: You are welcome! If you want to receive quality answers you have to provide all the meaningful information. If you could update your question with an example that better replicates your code I'll be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Do this change.It worked for me:

```
    <div style="width: 100px; height:200px; border: solid black 1px;overflow-x: auto">
    <div style="width: 120px; height: 50px;background-color:blue">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 30px;background-color:red;position:fixed;">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 120px; height: 50px;background-color:green">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this is what you want.